# Hyper-v and ubuntu 10.04 apt-get update

Tags: server, 10.10, updates, microsoft, hyper-v

I have issues with 10.04 and 10.10 servers. I'm trying to do `apt-get update command`, but it is stuck on **get**. There is some solutions in here: [apt-get update stuck on "Waiting for Headers" when using Windows XP ICS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19798/apt-get-update-stuck-on-waiting-for-headers).

I added this `Acquire::http::Pipeline-Depth="0"` to `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/piplining-off.conf` and it worked fine then.

Is there have been similar problems with Hyper-V and ubuntu 10.04/10.10?

Thank you for your answers

Answer (score 1):

Did not see this problem with Ubuntu LTS 10.04 and Ubuntu 10.10.

Everything works fine for me.

[Installing and configuring Linux Ubuntu 10.04 LTS under Hyper-V](http://translate.google.com/translate?js=n&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&layout=2&eotf=1&sl=ru&tl=en&u=http://blogs.technet.com/b/abeshkov/archive/2011/01/30/3383495.aspx)

Comment: Thansk for link. Did you do some special configurations for Hyper-v, or did you just go by the book? I need to check our network configurations, because I can't see that synthetic network.

Comment: Those settings didn't help me at all. It's little bit wierd