# How to analyze a "[Waiting for headers]" problem during "apt-get update"?

Tags: apt

`sudo apt-get update` sometimes becomes stucked:

```
...
99% [Waiting for headers]
```

This seems to be a common problem and can have several reasons. For example, on one machine, it was caused because I used a bad proxy server configuration.

Is there a way to systematically analyze the problem? It looked at the `man apt-get` but could not find any option that provides more information to isolate the problem. Are there any tools besides `apt-get` that I can use to get more insights?

Comment: This is a network connectivity problem, and is not specific to `apt-get`.

Comment: @Flimm My internet connection seems to be fine. I have no problem besides `apt-get update`. Installing new packages via `apt-get install` also worked. You may be right that `apt-get` does not cause the problem but at least for me it is some kind of blackbox. My question is what can I do isolate the problem?

Comment: Check out this link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/156650/apt-get-update-very-slow-stuck-at-waiting-for-headers?rq=1

Comment: @Mukund Thanks, that helped me to fix the problem. See my answer below.

Comment: I solved this problem simply by unpluging the wifi connection and connecting my PC directly via a cable.  So problem was somewhere in my wifi routers (OpenWrt). Unfortunatelly I am unable diagnose where...  :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to fix it. `http://debian.sur5r.net/i3/` (quantal, universe) did not respond. After disabling it, `apt-get update` succeeds.

Tips for the next one that runs into this problem:

1. Start `synaptic` and disable sources until `Reload` no longer hangs. Especially, 3rd party sources seem to be candidates.
2. Reactive your sources until you hit the one that causes problems.

`synaptic` is great for diagnostics. When `Reload` hangs and you abort it, it prints out the current repository. In my case, it was exactly the bad one:

```
Failed to fetch http://debian.sur5r.net/i3/dists/quantal/InRelease  
Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: Are you sure that you wouldn't see something similar to "Failed to fetch http://debian.sur5r.net/i3/dists/quantal/InRelease  
Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead." even using plain apt-get?

Comment: @vasa1 No, it just hangs forever. When you abort it by pressing ctrl-c, it does not print anything before it quits.

Answer (score 12):

Better still, just do:

```
apt-get -o Debug::Acquire::http=true update
```

Comment: This is great! It helped to show that there was actually a problem with my firewall's HTTP proxy -- which I had forgotten I even had! :)