# Graphic driver segfault on Lenovo G780 for Nvidia GeForce GT 635M

Tags: 12.10, nvidia, lenovo

I recently installed Ubuntu 12.10 on my new Lenovo G780. I followed [these instructions](http://www.noobslab.com/2012/10/install-latest-nvidia-drivers-in-ubuntu.html) to install the drivers for my graphics card. When I reboot I can log in, but nothing happens after. I switched to a virtual terminal and ran `dmesg`. I got this:

`[  202.106458] compiz[2028]: segfault at 30 ip 00007fb16b0b7576 sp 00007ffffa1d27f0 error 4 in libgrid.so[7fb16b0a5000+27000]`

This was the error I got when I installed the drivers:

```
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/dell_latitude
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/put_your_quirs
```

I let the system do a bug report, but I was wondering if anybody has found a fix. Thanks for your time. If there's any other information about the computer you need, let me know.

Comment: What were your issues with the `nvidia-current` or `nvidia-current-updates` drivers provided from the repositories before you installed drivers from the x-swat ppa?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. My laptop uses Optimus technology, so I needed to install Bumblebee to get the NVIDIA drivers to work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Oke make you ready to download some stuff. 
first remove that ppa and what you have installed

```
sudo apt-get remove nvidia-current
sudo apt-add-repository --remove ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
```

And run these command in the following order:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
sudo apt-get install linux-source
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install nvidia-313
sudo reboot
```

I have used this commands succesfully on a GTX670 and a 315M.

Comment: When I run `sudo apt-get update`, it sticks at 100% with "Waiting for Headers".

Comment: This is an other problem. I suggest you look here http://askubuntu.com/questions/156650/apt-get-update-very-slow-stuck-at-waiting-for-headers . And for acces the settings you can do `gnome-control-center`.