# sudo apt-get update stuck at 100% [Waiting for headers]?

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates, update-manager, security

Here is the sample

```
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/main Translation-en             
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/multiverse Translation-en       
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/restricted Translation-en       
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/universe Translation-en         
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/main Translation-en_US          
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/universe Translation-en_US
Ign http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com raring Release.gpg
Ign http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates Release.gpg
Ign http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports Release.gpg
Ign http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com raring Release
Ign http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates Release
Ign http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports Release
100% [Waiting for headers]
```

Or if I stop this and try to install any software it gives the other error (I tried vlc and this time)

```
Package dependencies cannot be resolved
This error could be caused by required additional software packages which are missing or not installable. Furthermore there could be a conflict between software packages which are not allowed to be installed at the same time.
Details
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
vlc-plugin-notify: Depends: vlc-nox (= 2.0.8-0ubuntu0.13.04.1) but 2.0.8-0ubuntu0.13.04.1 is to be installed
                   Depends: libc6 (>= 2.8) but 2.17-0ubuntu5 is to be installed
                   Depends: libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 (>= 2.22.0) but 2.28.0-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
                   Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.12.0) but 2.36.0-1ubuntu2 is to be installed
                   Depends: libgtk2.0-0 (>= 2.8.0) but 2.24.17-0ubuntu2 is to be installed
vlc-plugin-pulse: Depends: vlc-nox (= 2.0.8-0ubuntu0.13.04.1) but 2.0.8-0ubuntu0.13.04.1 is to be installed
                  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.8) but 2.17-0ubuntu5 is to be installed
                  Depends: libpulse0 (>= 1:1.0) but 1:3.0-0ubuntu6 is to be installed
```

Please Help !

Comment: Same question. Get your answer here [updates get stuck at 100%][1]


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/156650/apt-get-update-very-slow-stuck-at-waiting-for-headers

Comment: you also have unmet dependencies. `sudo apt-get install -f` should do the trick for those.

Comment: [There is the Solution to this problem](http://askubuntu.com/questions/156650/apt-get-update-very-slow-stuck-at-waiting-for-headers)