# apt-get update stuck at 100%[Waiting for headers] at "Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe Translation-en"

Tags: 12.04, networking, server, apt

Not sure what has happened to my Ubuntu 13.04 server. It is pretty much a LAMP & SAMBA server only, no other apps installed, no shell, command line only.

I run an apt-get update a fortnight ago and it all worked fine. Today I notice another set of updates available so I try again, and I keep getting stuck at:

```
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe Translation-en
100% [Waiting for headers]
```

Every time it stops there. Letting it go for a while it eventually gives the message

```
Err http://au.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release.gpg
  Connection failed
```

I tried solutions from the following article (and the links in it) but I have not fixed the issue:

[apt-get update very slow, stuck at “Waiting for headers”](https://askubuntu.com/questions/156650/apt-get-update-very-slow-stuck-at-waiting-for-headers)

I live in Australia and my Internet speed test is showing 500Kbps right now. Any suggestions are really welcome.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Restore your repositories to default
http://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories

Comment: I had the same problem. Just restore your repositories
http://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be a temporary problem with the mirror. I also can't reach the mirror at the moment of writing. Launchpad [lists mirrors in Australia](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors). Most of them are in a good shape and you could also choose them. The Ubuntu Wiki also has a page on [Australian apt mirrors](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/AustralianTeam/LocalAptMirrors).