# Trouble with " waiting for headers "

Tags: 12.04, apt, updates, update-manager

It seems duplicate but really it's not, I'm really tired of testing all solutions and reaching no success. even I'm thinking about going back to windows because I had several problems with Ubuntu 12.04 .

When I type `sudo apt-get update`

> `0% [Waiting for headers]`

appear and stick at this percent and sometimes it goes up to 15 or 30 or ...
I change my server from sources.list and also I chose best server from update manager and even pick software update's checkbox tick but eventually no change to my problem.

Do you have any idea to fix it? I can't wait anymore.
thanks in advance

Comment: It seems like the "best server" is not a very good server. Perhaps you can try another server?

Comment: @Jos thanks but I test several server not just best server even nearest one and so on

Comment: @Rinzwind Sorry I edit my question, it is 12.04

Comment: are you behind a proxy?

Comment: @Rinzwind few days ago I tried to install squid but because I didn't know and didn't understand how to configure and use it correctly I did `sodu apt-get remove squid`. is that correct? and finally I don't think so that I'm behind proxy

Comment: possible duplicate of [apt-get update very slow, stuck at "Waiting for headers"](http://askubuntu.com/questions/156650/apt-get-update-very-slow-stuck-at-waiting-for-headers)

Comment: @HosseinSh,  a long time, I expect that you reinstalled the system. Could you please update if you have solved it?