# Cannot finish a simple update

Tags: 14.04, updates

I simply cannot finish an update for several hours now, I have no idea what's the issue could be? When I run `sudo apt-get update` it runs all the way down until it gets stuck at the end:

```
100% [Connecting to us.archive.ubuntu.com (91.189.91.23)]
```

When I try to ping it:

```
~$ ping -c4 91.189.91.23
PING 91.189.91.23 (91.189.91.23) 56(84) bytes of data.

--- 91.189.91.23 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 2999ms
```

When I ping Google:

```
~$ ping -c4 google.com
PING google.com (216.58.209.206) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from bud02s22-in-f14.1e100.net (216.58.209.206): icmp_seq=1 ttl=54 time=69.5 ms
64 bytes from bud02s22-in-f14.1e100.net (216.58.209.206): icmp_seq=2 ttl=54 time=69.5 ms
64 bytes from bud02s22-in-f14.1e100.net (216.58.209.206): icmp_seq=3 ttl=54 time=69.5 ms
64 bytes from bud02s22-in-f14.1e100.net (216.58.209.206): icmp_seq=4 ttl=54 time=69.5 ms

--- google.com ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3004ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 69.508/69.514/69.520/0.186 ms
```

I tried switching from Main Server to US server and in Great Britain and acts the same. Can somebody give me a hint what's going on?

Comment: the issue currently avoided using one of random servers in EU but still figuring it out, maybe it's just temporary...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be experiencing a network problem.

Try changing your download mirror to one with a better connection to you as according to [this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/157163/119301).

Here's the skinny on how to do it:

1. Open **Software Sources**
2. Click the *Download From* dropdown.
3. Select *Other*
4. Click the *Select Best Server* button.
5. Wait for this to finish.
6. Click *OK* to close the mirror selection dialog.
7. Click *Close* to close the **Software Sources** window.
8. Enter your user password when prompted.
9. Wait for process to finish.

Now you should be all set.

Comment: thank you but I'm already using it ;) though I've been using main server for a year with no issues.

Comment: I'll trust you on that @JoKeR

Answer (score 0):

I had to do a manual repository change after installing Ubuntu 12.10.
Took me a while to arrive at this solution.
  You will need to find the sources.list file on your system. Having found it,
open a terminal and enter this command  $ sudo gedit .../sources.list.
  You will be prompted for your password - enter that and gedit will open the file. Once the file is open you will want to change 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
to 'old-releases.ubuntu.com'. Change all instances in the file. Once satisfied
that this is correctly done, save the file and close gedit. Should be no need
to restart system, just try the 'sudo apt-get update' and see if this behaves
correctly. Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm not using **old-release**, I use current LTS release, it will make no sense.