# Why does apt-get keep waiting for headers on Oracle repository?

Tags: apt, oracle

I have this at the end of my `/etc/apt/sources.list` to retrieve Oracle code:

```
deb http://oss.oracle.com/debian unstable main non-free
```

When I run `sudo apt-get update`, the app gets stuck displaying this message:

```
100% [Waiting for headers]
```

If I remove this, `apt-get update` runs without error.

Is there a new, recommended URL for Oracle products and, generally, how do you fix this problem?

I am pretty sure this did not happen on 11.10 and has only started with the move to 12.04.

I have seen these answers and they do not help:

- [apt-get update stuck on "Waiting for Headers" when using Windows XP ICS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19798/apt-get-update-stuck-on-waiting-for-headers)
- http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1689579
- http://muffinresearch.co.uk/archives/2010/03/30/linux-fix-for-apt-get-update-waiting-for-headers/
- http://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php?57567-Ubuntu-problems-on-update

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This a problem with the repository, and *not* 12.04. I observe this problem on both:

- 11.10 (snipped):

  ```
  Hit http://security.ubuntu.com oneiric-security/multiverse Translation-en
  Hit http://security.ubuntu.com oneiric-security/restricted Translation-en
  Get:63 http://security.ubuntu.com oneiric-security/universe Translation-en [29.9 kB]
  99% [Waiting for headers]
  ```
- 12.04 (snipped):

  ```
  Ign http://archive.canonical.com precise/partner Translation-en_US   
  Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-en
  Ign http://archive.canonical.com precise/partner Translation-en
  98% [Waiting for headers]
  ```

Please remove that repository, it seems to contain a handful of packages last updated in 2007 at any rate.

Comment: I added that repository because I want the Oracle tools associated. If I remove the repo, then I don't get the tools (like Oracle XE). I'm looking for a solution that gives me the Oracle tools and leaves apt-get unbroken.

Answer (score 5):

**What I think is causing the problem:**
The problem is that oss.oracle.com enforces use of HTTPS which is a good thing. The bad thing about it is that the certificate that is being used isn't considered trusted (either because it's expired or is self signed etc).

**Proposed solution:**
If I knew how to make apt accept all HTTPS certifiates, I'd post that here as a solution (but I'm still search myself for info on how to do this).

**After some digging:**
I did find out how to make APT not verify certificates: Acquire:https::Verify-Peer false; but that didn't help.

**The workaround:**
Regardless, I downloaded the deb files manually and installed them. It's an old version of Oracle Express and I can't get it to run on a virtual Debian Squeeze machine. I'm giving up on trying to use this deb archive.

Comment: I did find out how to make APT not verify certificates: `Acquire:https::Verify-Peer false;` but that didn't help.

Comment: Regardless, I downloaded the deb files manually and installed them. It's an old version of Oracle Express and I can't get it to run on a virtual Debian Squeeze machine. I'm giving up on trying to use this deb archive.