# How to install Oracle XE from broken Oracle repository?

Tags: apt, oracle

The [identical] instructions from these sites used to work:

- http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/linux/xe-on-kubuntu-087822.html
- http://www.debianhelp.co.uk/oracle.htm
- http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-install-linux-oracle-database-xe-server/

Now they don't because the `apt-get update` step hangs, as described here:

[Why does apt-get keep waiting for headers on Oracle repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/158148/why-does-apt-get-keep-waiting-for-headers-on-oracle-repository)

What is an alternative way to download and install Oracle XE?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *What is an alternative way to download and install Oracle XE?*

If you need the Oracle XE packages from that repository, simply installing them manually is the best option; they haven't been updated since 2006, so it's unlikely they will ever be.

1. Go to https://oss.oracle.com/debian/dists/unstable/non-free/binary-i386/

   [image]
2. Download the .debs you need.
3. Open in Software Center to install, or install from the terminal with `sudo dpkg -i name-of-deb`.

Comment: Cool, thanks. Really, I only ever needed this so that cx-Oracle, a python package, would run correctly, and it seemed to need more junk than just environment variables... Thanks again.