# Having some trouble authenticating via proxy in order to use apt-get successfully on a corporate network

Tags: networking, apt, proxy

*Apologies if this is a basic question, I've recently taken ownership of our department's internal server so I'm having to deal with issues beyond my (very basic) knowledge.*

---

**Context**

Our server is on a corporate network which requires corporate proxy authentication (e.g. enter corporate username and password). This is not an issue on the Windows machines on that network - when a web browser is opened the user is prompted to authenticate. However, when using a browser on Linux the user is not prompted to authenticate, the browser simply shows a message saying authentication is required.

---

**Problem 1 - Internet Access would be useful**

At the moment I have to walk to my desk on another floor if I need to look something up, because I cannot get Internet access from this machine since I cannot* (*do not know how to) authenticate. It would be useful to have the ability to authenticate so I can use a web browser.

---

**Problem 2 - Packages cannot be updated**

When I attempt to perform updates using `sudo apt-get update` or `sudo apt-get install [package]`, there are errors which I believe are caused due to lack of authentication.

After performing `sudo apt-get update`, I get errors like `W: Failed to fetch [link] 401 Authorization Required`. (For some reason some http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/ sources work correctly, and some throw the same error).

This is a major problem, as I need to be able to update packages on the server.

---

**Steps Taken**

- I have installed cntlm via `sudo apt-get install cntlm` (it works from one of the few ubuntu repositories that randomly work).
- I edited the configuration at `/etc/cntlm.conf` and added my username, the domain, and the proxy.
- I started the service (`sudo /etc/init.d/cntlm start`)
- I tested the service (`sudo cntlm -I -M http://www.google.com/`) and the response was `Config Profile 1/4... Auth not required (HTTP code: 307) Your proxy is open, you don't need another proxy.`

---

- I tried performing `sudo apt-get update` again and still receive the same error message. (`401 Authorization Required`)
- *(Whoops! My mistake! I see I need to configure apt proxy settings manually...)*
- I added the line `Acquire::http::Proxy "http://localhost:3128";` to `/etc/apt/apt.conf`.
- I restarted `cntlm`. (`sudo /etc/init.d/cntlm stop`, `sudo /etc/init.d/cntlm start`)

---

- I performed `sudo apt-get update` ... and it hit `0% [Waiting for headers] [Waiting for headers] [Waiting for headers] [Waiting f` - and just stopped there.
- I performed `sudo apt-get clean` before performing `sudo apt-get update` - this started working and then stopped at `19% [Waiting for headers]`
- I performed `sudo apt-get clean` again before performing `sudo apt-get update` - this started working and then stopped at `0% [Waiting for headers]`
- I tried this a third time (`sudo apt-get clean`, `sudo apt-get update`) and it stopped at `20% [Waiting for headers]`

---

- I researched this subsequent problem and found [an answer on AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/19811) suggesting this may be an issue with IPv6 causing ICS to halt for a while when it receives concurrent connections.
- I checked the `/etc/sysctl.conf` file and discovered the IPv6 already appears to be disabled... (The lines `net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1`, `net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1`, and `net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1` are already in the config file.)
- *(I'm now drawing a bit of a blank! The symptoms match the hypothesized IPv6 issue however if it is already disabled that doesn't seem to be able to be the cause)*
- I performed `sudo apt-get clean` and `sudo apt-get update` a fourth time *(What the hell - why not?)* and it hung on `24% [Waiting for Headers]` this time, but first it hit a bunch of repositories. A repository which used to trigger errors did not do so now (`http://cran.rstudio.com trusty /`) but one which used to trigger errors now triggered a different error, `Received HTTP code 501 from proxy after CONNECT`.

Comment: Welcome. For the problem 1 have you tried to do `ssh -X yourUsername@yourip` from the other floor? Try in advance from your own computer to do `pgrep -l sshd` to see if the daemon sshd is running. If you are able to connect with your computer after you can make run your browser too from shll e.g. `firefox -no-remote`.

Comment: Hi, thank you! Forgive me but as I say I'm very new so I don't really understand what any of those commands do or what you are asking me to check. I will give them a try but it's going over my head a little I'm afraid! I do most of my work on the Linux server downstairs by using putty from my Windows 7 PC and doing everything via command line.

Comment: I used another Linux server (on the same network as my Windows 7 PC upstairs) to perform the first command (`ssh -X myUsername@myIp`) which worked correctly.

Comment: If I perform the `pgrep -l sshd` by ssh-ing in (`Putty > Upstairs Server > Downstairs Server`) it shows three sshd numbers, and if I try going in to the Downstairs Server directly (`Putty > Downstairs Server`) it shows five sshd numbers. I'm not sure what the daemon sshd is or how to check if it is running?

Answer (score 0):

You must tell apt-get to use your proxy. In a shell, type:

export _http_proxy=htp://user:password@proxyserver:port
apt-get update

If this works, you can make the change persistent:

vi /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/proxy

and then

Acquire::http::Proxy "htp://user:password@proxyserver:port";

Comment: Notice the missing t in http addresses, as I was not allowed to add "links"...

Comment: Forgive me if I'm mistaken, but I think I have completed this step? I added my proxy to `apt.conf` - `Acquire::http::Proxy "htp://localhost:3128";` which should direct it through `cntlm` according to instructions.