# apt-get update stuck at 0% [waiting for headers]?

Tags: 16.04, apt

Whenever I try to update using `apt-get` update it stuck at

```
0% [Waiting for headers]
```

I tried with my phone hotspot, on that it works fine but while I am using the Wi-Fi connection of my ISP it stuck. I am able to open websites in a browser, and my internet connection is totally fine.

I tried changing the server to download from and selected 'main server' and rebooted but it is not working, still stuck at

```
0% [Waiting for headers]
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: yes, I am able to open websites in a browser, and my internet connection is totally fine.

Comment: yes i rebooted it but it doesn't helped me

Comment: Please help me, anybody, how can i solve this issue, it's very urgent

Comment: See the following Q&As: https://askubuntu.com/questions/94831/stuck-at-0-waiting-for-headers, https://askubuntu.com/questions/19798/apt-get-update-stuck-on-waiting-for-headers-when-using-windows-xp-ics, https://askubuntu.com/questions/156650/apt-get-update-very-slow-stuck-at-waiting-for-headers

Comment: i removed the chrome update from other software update and it works now

Answer (score 1):

I removed the Google Chrome update from update manager > other software. And it works fine. What I found is may be the Google server takes a lot of time through my isp so I feel it's better to upgrade chrome manually.

Answer (score 0):

Run the following

```
sudo nano /etc/gai.conf
```

Scroll with arrow keys down to where it says:

```
#precedence ::ffff:0:0/96  100
```

remove the comment (#) and save it